# How the size of a struct containing bitset fields is calculated

Tags: c++

Can somebody explain me how the size of following struct containing bitset fields is being calculated. I was expecting size of 80 bits but it is giving me 88 bytes instead. I'm using gcc compiler(gcc version 4.8.5 20150623). This is my sample code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct st
{
    std::bitset<8> hdr;
    std::bitset<11> carId;
    std::bitset<1> latSignInd;
    std::bitset<11> lat;
    std::bitset<1> lonSignInd;
    std::bitset<12> lon;
    std::bitset<1> altSignInd; // always poitive
    std::bitset<17> alt;
    std::bitset<2> spare;
    std::bitset<8> chkSum;
    std::bitset<8> EOM;
};
#pragma pack(pop)


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << sizeof(struct st) << std::endl;

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Can you tell me what needs to be done in order to make this struct exactly 80 bytes, since I need to adhere to this message structure.

Comment: libstdc++ implements bitset using `unsigned long`: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00775_source.html so on 64-bit platforms `std::bitset` will be 8 bytes, will 11 bitsets you have 88 bytes

Comment: Do you mean 80 bytes or 80 bits? If bits you can't implement this using bitset, you need bit fields: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field

Comment: @Harry if needing a specific structure, make it manual. Do not use std::bitset. Create your own structure that has 80 bytes and set the bits internally manually.

Comment: Use bitfields not bitsets...

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Actually I was thinking of using std::memcpy directly to copy the received socket data present in a char array into struct and print the data like "std::cout << st.lat << std::endl;"

Comment: @AlanBirtles Can you provide a sample example

Comment: `struct st {
  long hdr:8;
  long  carId:11;
  long latSignInd:1;
  long lat:11;
  long lonSignInd:1;
  long  lon:12;
  long altSignInd:1; // always poitive
  long  alt:17;
  long spare:2;
  long chkSum:8;
  long EOM:8;
};`gives 80 bits (not bytes).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I thought this would be 16 bytes since long is of size 64 bits,  which gets occupied till field spare and the next 64 bits by remaining fields(chkSum and EOM).

Comment: I think the type of the bitfield elements doesn't generally affect the memory layout of the structure (which is implementation defined)

Comment: @Harry ok then use `uint32_t`. (it works with long because you used the pack pragma.